# Calculate and get sum of an array using ionic angular

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, sum

I'm trying to get the sum of all the value that is on the array, I don't know how to do it. Here's my set of codes.

```
    <ion-content>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>
        <h4>{{question.title}}</h4>
      </ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-text>
        <h6>Rating:</h6>
      </ion-text>
      <div margin-vertical text-center>
            <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="question.answer">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-radio value=0></ion-radio>
                <ion-label> Not at all</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-radio value=2></ion-radio>
                <ion-label>For some of the time</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-radio value=4></ion-radio>
                <ion-label>For most of the time</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-radio value=5></ion-radio>
                <ion-label>For all of the time</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-radio-group>
      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
  <div margin-vertical text-center>
    <ion-button (click)='getQuestionResults()'>SUBMIT</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and here is the ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export interface question {
title: string;
answer: number;
}
@Component({
selector: 'app-evaluation',
templateUrl: './evaluation.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./evaluation.page.scss'],
})
export class EvaluationPage implements OnInit {

questions: question[] = [];

constructor(private route: Router) { }

home(){
  this.route.navigate(['/home']);
}
Result(){
  this.route.navigate(['/result']);
}

ngOnInit() {
  // Questions
  for(let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    this.questions.push({ title: `Little interest or pleasure in doing things`, answer: 
undefined });
    this.questions.push({ title: `Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless`, answer: undefined });
    this.questions.push({ title: `Trouble falling or staying asleep, or sleeping too much`, 
answer: undefined });
    this.questions.push({ title: `Feeling tired or having little energy`, answer: undefined });
    this.questions.push({ title: `Often has difficulty organizing tasks or activities`, 
answer: undefined });
    this.questions.push({ title: `Trouble concentrating on things, such as reading the 
newspaper or watching television`, answer: undefined });
    this.questions.push({ title: `Feeling bad about yourself — or that you are a failure or 
have let yourself or your family down`, answer: undefined });
  
    }
  }
  getQuestionResults() {
    console.log(this.questions);
  }
```

[image]
this is what it looks like in the console, the value I set on the HTML file for an answer is an integer and I want to add all the answers to get the quiz result. How can I sum up all the values and get the result after getting the total result I want to put an equivalent value to it and print it to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, you have some lack of basic programming knowledge. Anyway, you can use one of these options:

Just sum in `for` cycle:

```
let sumA = 0;
for (const q of this.questions) {
    sumA += Number(q.answer || 0);
}
```

Or use `reduce` (or `map` with `reduce`):

```
const sumB = this.questions
    .map(q => Number(q.answer || 0))
    .reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
```

You should keep in mind that you can get `string` value from your HTML despite your type declaration. You need to typecast your value to `number`.

Also, this value can be `undefined`. `value || 0` can help handle `undefined` values in sum.

Answer (score 1):

I think Array.reduce would fit your problem. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
let initialValue = 0;
let sum = this.questions?.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
    return currentValue?.answer ? accumulator + +currentValue.answer : accumulator;
}, initialValue)
```